# Query entities by the logical operator OR with Fiware Orion

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I dont be able to retrieve entities form Orion querys with 2 conditions by the logical operator OR.

For example, if I want to retrieve the entities that have `temperature > 20 OR humidity enter code here< 50.`
But I only can retrieve the query by the logical operator AND:

```
http:// localhost:1026/v2/entities?q=temperature>20;humidity<50
```

Also I try with  | to separate the conditions, like this:

```
http:// localhost:1026/v2/entities?q=temperature>20|humidity<50
```

But gived me the next error:

```
{
    "error": "BadRequest",
    "description": "forbidden characters in String Filter"
}
```

How I could to retrieve queries to Orion by te logical operator OR?

Answer (score 2):

It is correct that the comma-separated **q StringFilter** items are ANDed together. As far as I remember, we never implemented any OR for StringFilters.

To achieve what you want I'd propose to do two queries and merge the results. Sorry ...

The spec is [here](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/). It says clearly:

*The Simple Query Language provides a simplified syntax to retrieve entities which match a set of conditions. A query is composed by a list of statements separated by the ';' character. Each statement expresses a matching condition. **The query returns all the entities that match all the matching conditions (AND logical operator).***